# In VS2017 Android sdk is empty - no platforms or tools

Tags: android, sdk, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms iOS/Android app in VS2017.  The previewer works fine in iOS but not in android.  I've cleaned and rebuilt but the problem persists.  I've tried to update to latest in sdk but it comes up blank?

I've attached screenshots of the sdk manager window and Xamarin settings.  What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's what the 2nd picture is . . .

Answer (score 0):

In Android SDKs and Tools, click on three dots in right top corner and set up Android SDK location to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk".

After that, it should pick up all installed modules and show them in the list.